# Unexpected JDWP Error 35 when trying debug in Android Studio. Target VM is not paused by breakpoint request

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to start debbug session in Android Studio 4.0 (Run->Attach to Process). Debug session starts but in the Variables window I get following error: *Target VM is not paused by breakpoint request. Evaluation of methods is not possible in this mode*.

idea.log file:

```
com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Unexpected JDWP Error: 35
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.JDWPException.toJDIException(JDWPException.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.StackFrameImpl.getArgumentValues(StackFrameImpl.java:358)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerUtilsEx.getArgumentValues(DebuggerUtilsEx.java:586)
    at com.intellij.debugger.jdi.StackFrameProxyImpl.getArgumentValues(StackFrameProxyImpl.java:374)
    at com.intellij.debugger.jdi.LocalVariablesUtil.fetchValues(LocalVariablesUtil.java:152)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.JavaStackFrame.buildVariables(JavaStackFrame.java:336)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.JavaStackFrame.buildVariablesThreadAction(JavaStackFrame.java:237)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.JavaStackFrame$1.threadAction(JavaStackFrame.java:124)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.events.DebuggerContextCommandImpl.contextAction(DebuggerContextCommandImpl.java:71)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.events.SuspendContextCommandImpl.action(SuspendContextCommandImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.events.DebuggerCommandImpl.run(DebuggerCommandImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.processEvent(DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.java:151)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.processEvent(DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.java:29)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread.run(InvokeThread.java:138)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread.access$100(InvokeThread.java:19)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread$WorkerThreadRequest.lambda$run$0(InvokeThread.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread$WorkerThreadRequest.run(InvokeThread.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Android device is connected through USB cable and available in the ADB. I tried to:

- start ADB root mode (adb root)
- restart ADB with adb kill-server and adb start-server
- change Android Studio to 3.6
- remove application from the device to be sure that sources are in sync.

Application is based on the C++ and uses NDK.